# Why is re.findall() not going to next line of txt file to search for letters?

Tags: python, regex, findall

Why is re.findall returning alphabets instead of words?

```
Tint = open('poem.txt')
text1 = Tint.read()
output = []
for line in text1:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\blittle\b', text1):
        output.append(line)
```

Currently my expected output is `Twinkle Twinkle little` but what i am getting with this code is `T`,`w`,...

I also want the code to be able to search in next line. For example: if I say `re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\wonder\b', text1)` it should give `Twinkle Twinkle little star How I wonder`. How can I do this? `for line in text1` is not helping.

PS: `poem.txt` contains 4 lines of the poem `Twinkle twinkle little star`

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1**: `text1` is a string object, then stating `for line in text1` means that `line` will be a character.

**Error 2**: You are searching every time in the whole `text1` and not in the single line.

I think you want something like this:

```
Tint=open('poem.txt')
text1=Tint.readlines()
output=[]
for line in text1:
    if re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\blittle\b', line.rstrip()) :
        output.append(line)
```

Notice the usage of `readlines()` function, so that `text1` won't be a string but an array of lines.

Comment: Thanks, this helped in getting words as output instead of alphabet. Now the output i am getting is "Twinkle Twinkle little star". But i want output as "Twinkle Twinkle little". 
Also,i need that if i make it "re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\bwonder\b', line.rstrip()), it should be able to give me "Twinkle Twinkle little star, 
How i wonder"

PS: poem.txt contains something like this:

Twinkle Twinkle little star,
How I wonder what you are,

Up above the world so high,

Notice: "wonder" is in a new line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) of `re.findall`.

The answer to your specific problem is `re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\blittle\b', text1,re.DOTALL)`or`re.findall(r'\bTwinkle\b.*?\blittle\b', text1,re.MULTILINE)`.